# callback vs on function in sendsignedtransaction

Tags: web3js

I am deploying a smart contract using web3js and it works perfectly. But i was made aware of my incorrect use of callbacks. I got some basic understanding of promievents from https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.1/callbacks-promises-events.html and rewrote my code as below based on the samples here : https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth.html#sendsignedtransaction :

```js
web3.eth.getTransactionCount(account, (err, txCount) => {
    if (err!=null) {console.log('error executing web3.eth.getTransactionCount: ', err)}
    else{
        console.log('txCount: ',txCount)

        const txObject = {
            nonce: web3.utils.toHex(txCount),
            gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(1000000),
            gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('0', 'gWei')),
            data: contractByteCode
        }

        const tx = new EthereumTx(txObject,{common: customCommon})

        tx.sign(privateKey)

        const serializedTransaction = tx.serialize()
        const raw = '0x' + serializedTransaction.toString('hex')

        web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(raw)
        .on('transactionHash',(hash) => {
            console.log('txHash:', hash)
        })
        .on('receipt',(receipt) => {
            console.log('receipt', receipt)
        })
        .on('error', console.error)
    }

})
```

I did this based on the principle that the callback in getTransactionCount() might execute at any future time, so i should use the return value txCount only within the callback. That is why the entire code is inside the callback function.

But i am not sure about the sendsignedtransaction part. I am assuming that the ".on('transactionHash')" function will execute whenever a transactionHash event is emitted by the sendsignedtransaction function. Similarly the ".on('receipt')" function will execute whenever a receipt event is emitted by the sendsignedtransaction function. And the ".on('error')" function will execute whenever a error event is emitted by the sendsignedtransaction function. So everything works asynchronously without blocking my thread.

If my understanding is correct, then i am confused why this code just hangs in node when i intentionally put in an bug(by removing the "{common: customCommon}" parameter). Shouldn't it return immediately and do "console.error" ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the general scheme:

- `transactionHash` is fired right after the transaction is sent (almost immediately)
- `receipt` is fired when the transaction receipt is available
- `error` is fired if an error occurs at any point during this process
- `confirmation` is fired for every confirmation up to the 12th confirmation

Note that the more confirmations you wait for, the higher the probability of your transaction to remain in the blockchain forever is.

See [the official documentation](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth.html#eth-sendtransaction-return) (web3.js v1.2.0) for more details.

Comment: i got the confirmation 24 times in fact. Maybe it is decided by some configuration, though i did not change any configuration myself. I am using the Quorum network in Azure blockchain service.

Comment: @faizal: Yeah, that's a known issue in Web3.js. I thought they've fixed it in v1.2.0 but apparently they haven't (so the official documentation says 12, but the actual implementation yields 24).

Comment: I guess i am trying to figure out whether the "on" functions are sync or async. Based on my testing, it is synchronous since the command line hangs till an output is logged on the console. But as per the documentation, callbacks are async. That would make me question are these "on" functions categorized as callbacks, promises, events, promievents.. all the terms are getting mixed up in my head.

Comment: @faizal: Of course they're asynchronous - they take as input a callback to be executed when the corresponding event is fired. That said, it doesn't make either one of them an `async` function (which you would need to `await` for). So AFAIK, none of them returns a `Promise` object. And I agree that trying to mix `on`/`then` with `async`/`await` can be rather confusing.

Comment: that's exactly the kind of explanation that confuses me:) your first line says it is async, but next line says it is not async. the problem might be i am too new to javascript.

Comment: I said **asynchronous**, not `async`. A function can be asynchronous without using the keyword `async` (which was in fact introduced in later versions of Javascript). For a function which is asynchronous but not declared `async`, there is no point in using `await` because it will not really make it run synchronously until completion. But this topic in general is not related to Ethereum, so you might wanna search it on other forums as well (e.g., Stack Overflow).

Comment: oh k, i was not aware of the async keyword. Makes sense now :) But i still don't get why the command line does not return control to me immediately upon execution, if the "on" functions are supposed to be asynchronous. Shouldn't the sendSignedTransaction() immediately exit giving me control without waiting for the "on" functions to do the console.log? I will try searching in stackoverflow as suggested.

Comment: @faizal: Yes, it should return immediately. Add a `console.log` statement right before the line `web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(raw)` and right after the line `.on('error', console.error)` in order to verify this.

Comment: Interesting! ```web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(raw)``` is asynchronous in the sense that subsequent commands get executed before the callbacks within the "on" functions. But the javascript console itself does not return control to me until ```console.log('receipt', receipt)``` completes.

Comment: Of course, because the entire process (your script executed by NodeJS) is blocked until those callbacks are executed.

Comment: @goodvibration 25 times (0-24)